# (Numpy C API) Iterating over a single array: NpyIter vs for loop (with PyArray_DATA)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-c-api

I am writing some C extension code for a python module.
The function I want to write is (in python)

```
output = 1./(1. + input)
```

where `input` is a numpy array of any shape.

Originally I was using [`NpyIter_MultiNew`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.iterator.html?highlight=sum#c.NpyIter_MultiNew):

```
static PyObject *
helper_calc1(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){

    PyObject * input;
    PyObject * output = NULL;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &input)){
        return NULL;
    }

    // -- input -----------------------------------------------
    PyArrayObject * in_arr;

    in_arr = (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_FROM_OTF(input, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY);
    if (in_arr == NULL){
        goto fail;
    }

    // -- set up iterator -------------------------------------
    PyArrayObject * op[2];
    npy_uint32 op_flags[2];
    npy_uint32 flags;

    op[0] = in_arr;
    op_flags[0] = NPY_ITER_READONLY;

    op[1] = NULL;
    op_flags[1] = NPY_ITER_WRITEONLY | NPY_ITER_ALLOCATE;

    flags = NPY_ITER_EXTERNAL_LOOP | NPY_ITER_BUFFERED | NPY_ITER_GROWINNER;

    NpyIter * iter = NpyIter_MultiNew(2, op,
                            flags, NPY_KEEPORDER, NPY_NO_CASTING,
                            op_flags, NULL);

    if (iter == NULL){
        goto fail;
    };

    NpyIter_IterNextFunc * iternext = NpyIter_GetIterNext(iter, NULL);
    if (iternext == NULL){
        NpyIter_Deallocate(iter);
        goto fail;
    };

    // -- iterate ---------------------------------------------
    npy_intp count;
    char ** dataptr = NpyIter_GetDataPtrArray(iter);
    npy_intp * strideptr = NpyIter_GetInnerStrideArray(iter);
    npy_intp * innersizeptr = NpyIter_GetInnerLoopSizePtr(iter);

    do {
        count = *innersizeptr;

        while (count--){

            *(double *) dataptr[1] = 1. / (1. + *(double *)dataptr[0]);

            dataptr[0] += strideptr[0];
            dataptr[1] += strideptr[1];
        }

    } while (iternext(iter));

    output = NpyIter_GetOperandArray(iter)[1];

    if (NpyIter_Deallocate(iter) != NPY_SUCCEED){
        goto fail;
    }

    Py_DECREF(in_arr);

    return output;

    fail:
        Py_XDECREF(in_arr);
        Py_XDECREF(output);
        return NULL;
}
```

However, since this is just a single array (i.e. I don't need to be concerned about broadcasting multiple arrays),
Is there any reason I can't iterate over the data myself using, [`PyArray_DATA`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_DATA), a `for` loop and the array size?

```
static PyObject *
helper_calc2(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){

    PyObject * input;
    PyObject * output = NULL;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", & in)){
        return NULL;
    }

    // -- input -----------------------------------------------
    PyArrayObject * in_arr;

    in_arr = (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_FROM_OTF(input, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY);
    if (in_arr == NULL){
        Py_XDECREF(in_arr);
        return NULL;
    }

    int ndim = PyArray_NDIM(in_arr);
    npy_intp * shape = PyArray_DIMS(in_arr);
    int size = (int) PyArray_SIZE(in_arr);

    double * in_data = (double *) PyArray_DATA(in_arr);

    output =  PyArray_SimpleNew(ndim, shape, NPY_DOUBLE);
    double * out_data = (double *) PyArray_DATA((PyArrayObject *) output);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        out_data[i] = 1. / (1. + in_data[i]);
    }

    Py_DECREF(in_arr);
    return output;

fail:
    Py_XDECREF(in_arr);
    Py_XDECREF(output);
    return NULL;
}
```

This second version runs more quickly and the code is shorter.

Are there any dangers I need to look out for when using,[`PyArray_DATA`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_DATA) with a `for` loop instead of [`NpyIter_MultiNew`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.iterator.html?highlight=sum#c.NpyIter_MultiNew)?

From the [`PyArray_DATA`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_DATA) documentation:

> If you have not guaranteed a contiguous and/or aligned array then be sure you understand how to access the data in the array to avoid memory and/or alignment problems.

But I believe that this is taken care of by [`PyArray_FROM_OTF`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_FROM_OTF) with the [`NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/c-api.array.html#c.NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY) flag.

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok in this case. Like you mentioned `NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY` with `PyArray_FROM_OTF` takes care of that issue and since you are casting the data pointer to the right type, you should be fine. However, in general, as you seem to be aware of, you can't use this approach if you are directly accepting a NumPy array from Python code.

Happy C extension writing.